# Disable Share Charm Screenshot on Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

I am trying to email photos using the "Share Charm" on Windows 8.  The only image that image I can obtain is a "Screenshot" image of my entire desktop. How do I disable screenshot?

Comment: I don't believe you can disable that feature.

Answer (score 0):

#### **"I am trying to email photos using the "Share Charm" on Windows 8."**

You need to make sure you are viewing the photo in an app downloaded from the Windows Store.

---

#### How to Use the Share Charm

> **This charm works only when used with apps from the Windows Store and it is used to share items using other apps**. These items can be web
> addresses (links), multimedia files (photos, video, music, etc), files
> from the SkyDrive, etc. Items can be shared via e-mail or with people
> from your People app.
>
> In Windows 8.1 you can also use this charm to take screenshots and
> share them using a Windows app.
>
> In Windows 8, trying to use the Share
> charm on the Desktop or from desktop applications will get you to
> nowhere, as it will only say that "Nothing can be shared from the
> desktop".

Source

[Introducing Windows 8.1: What are the Charms & How to Use them](http://www.7tutorials.com/introducing-windows-8-what-are-charms)

---

#### Tutorial

[Search, share, print, and more](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/charms-tutorial) for a mini tutorial.